# How to test whether two color are equivalent

Tags: ios, uicolor

I created a UIColor object and put it into an instant variable called `color`:

```
color = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Now I use an if statement to test whether this color is equivalent to another color:

```
if (color == [UIColor whiteColor]) {
    NSLog(@"Color is equivalent");
}
```

But this `NSLog` was never called. Is there a way to test whether two color are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[color isEqual:anotherColor]`